# Visual C++ Write BSTR to File

Tags: string, visual-c++, file-io, bstr

I am a newbie to C++. 
I am trying to write a BSTR to a CSV file, but the data when I print with wcout is not matching with data what's present in file.

```
BSTR tempString;
ofstream outputFile;
outputFile.open("C:\\data.csv",ios::out);
tempString = getData();
outputFile.write(tempString);
outputFile.close();

BSTR getData()
{
   BSTR KBIDValue;
   IStringCollection *KBID;
   KBID->get_Item(0,&KBIDValue);
   return KBIDValue;
}
```

1. If tempString = L"TestData" -> I am able to see the same value in
   file.
2. If tempString = getData(); where the function returns a BSTR,
   I am not able to see same value in file.

Could some please clarify this? Also please explain what exactly is the method to write BSTR to file?

EDIT: Added code

Comment: The is incorrect. `KBID` is not initialized with anything. Yes, as mentioned in answer below, function is not returning.

Comment: @Ajay Could you please validate the answer I posted?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have added the following lines of code in my program and giving the results correctly.

```
ofstream outputFile;
outputFile.open(filePath,ios::out);
outputFile << W2A(CString(tempString));
```

Comment: What is W2A? This is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything!!!

```
BSTR getData()
{
   BSTR KBIDValue;
   IStringCollection *KBID;
   KBID->get_Item(0,&KBIDValue);
   return KBIDValue;
}
```

However if you want to convert to some other form and print, [look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235631.aspx)

Comment: I have added the code now. Actually I forgot the return statement.

Comment: Could you please validate the answer I posted? Won't there be any data loss if I use those API to convert BSTR to CString and write to file?

Comment: Could you please validate my answer?